# Translate UDP packet data into human-readable form in PHP

Tags: php, binary, udp, hex, byte

I am receiving data over UDP in PHP.
After passing the buffer through bin2hex function in PHP I end up with something resembling the `Raw Data` as indicated below in the example

Here is my PHP code:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0" , 20500);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 512, 0, $from, $port);

$file = 'testudp.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new log line(s) to file
$current .= "New Connection " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " \n" . bin2hex($buf) . "\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
echo "Received connection from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
```

Which results in something like `83 05 01 02 03 04 05 01 01 01 02 00 01 4F B4 64 88 4F B4 64 88 13 BF 71 A8 BA 18 A5 06 00 00 1333 00 00 00 00 11 11 02 ...`
but without the spaces.

Example of Data and what it *ought* to translate to: note that the translation only begins after ther first 9 bytes, then address 2, then skips 2 again.

```
Raw Data:
 83 05 01 02 03 04 05 01 01 01 02 00 01 4F B4 64 88 4F B4 64
 88 13 BF 71 A8 BA 18 A5 06 00 00 1333 00 00 00 00 11 11 02 
 33 44 44 55 55 66 77 88 99 10 11 ?? 00 ?? 

Decoded:
  -------Message Header--------
  01           Service Type, for this message 1 = Acknowledged Request
  02           Message Type, for this message 2 = Event Report
  -------Event Report----------
  4FB46488     Update Time (5/17/12 @ 2:38pm)
  4FB46488     Time of Fix (5/17/12 @ 2:38pm)
  13BF71A8     Latitude (33.1313576)
  BA18A506     Longitude (-117.2790010)
  00001333     Altitude
  00000000     Speed
  1111         Heading
  02           Satellites
  33           Fix Status
  4444         Carrier
  5555         RSSI
  66           Comm State
  77           HDOP
  88           Inputs
  99           Unit Status
  10           Event Index
  11           Event Code
  ??           Accums (# of 4-byte Accum List values)
  00           Spare
  ??           Accum List (Varies depending on the # of Accums reporting)
```

I have tried various decoders hexadecimal to ascii, I've also tried unpack() in PHP all to no avail.
How do you translate the data into something resembling the example via PHP?
i.e. how would `BA18A506` end up giving me the data (unformatted or not) to correspond to `Longitude (-117.2790010)` in a human readable form?

**EDIT:**
The docs specify `Note that all bytes in multi-byte fields are transmitted in Net Endian format (Big Endian) where the most significant bits are transmitted first. For example, for a 32-bit field, bits 31-24 are transmitted first, 16-23 second, 8-15 third and 0-7 last`
if that helps at all.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation/manual of the source that's providing you that data. I mean how does `13BF71A8` translate to `Latitude (33.1313576)` if it isn't following a certain "standard" or "pattern" that's being set up from the provider ? A smaller example, I could give you `10`, you maybe would think of the number *ten*, but I actually meant *two*, since it's binary from my perspective.

Comment: @HamZa Many thanks for taking a look.  I have read the rather sparse documentation and they mention nothing specific hence I was hoping somebody here might have a clue.  Appreciate it.  If it isn't relevant I'll delete the question.

Comment: Did you solve decoding of the packet? Could you share what you end up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unpack() or unpack() per substr() of the binary data should in the end get you where you want. But as HamZa mentions, you have to know what format it is...

```
$test = "\x06\xA5\x18\xBA";
var_dump(unpack('l',$test));
```

result:

```
-1172790010
```

Just add the . on the correct place

Sample code to unpack first part (extend / correct where needed)

Change your code to recieve into a buffer instead of a file:
    socket_recv($socket, $buf, 512, 0);

Then you can use the buffer $buf (for now i enter the sample data you provided)

```
// Now we use some test data
$buf = "\x83\x05\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x01\x01\x01\x02\x00\x01\x4F\xB4\x64\x88\x4F\xB4\x64\x88\x13\xBF\x71\xA8\xBA\x18\xA5\x06\x00\x00\x13\x33\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x11\x02\x33\x44\x44\x55\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\x10\x11";

// field definition
$fields = array();
$fields['header'] = array(9, 'c*');
$fields['serviceType'] = array(1, 'c');
$fields['messageType'] = array(1, 'c');
$fields['skip'] = array(2, 'c');
$fields['updateTime'] = array(4, 'l');
$fields['fixTime'] = array(4, 'l');
$fields['longitude'] = array(4, 'l');
$fields['latitude'] = array(4, 'l');
$fields['altitude'] = array(4, 'l');
$fields['speed'] = array(4, 'l');
// etc.

$values = array();
$start = 0;
foreach($fields as $type=>$setting) {
    list($len, $format) = $setting;
    $values[$type] = unpack($format, strrev(substr($buf, $start, $len)));
    $start += $len;
}

var_dump($values);
```

Will output something like:

```
["serviceType"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
["messageType"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
["skip"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
["updateTime"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(1337222280)
}
["fixTime"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(1337222280)
}
["longitude"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(331313576)
}
["latitude"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(-1172790010)
}
["altitude"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(4915)
}
["speed"]=>
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Just divide latitude and longitude by 10000000 (10M) to get the real longitude and latitude

Comment: My apologies, I should have put that in the question. In answer to your question `Note that all bytes in multi-byte fields are transmitted in Net Endian format (Big Endian) where the most significant bits are transmitted first. For example, for a 32-bit field, bits 31-24 are transmitted first, 16-23 second, 8-15 third and 0-7 last` is the only thing I can get from the docs.

Comment: Ok this makes it WAY more easy.

Comment: Wow - thank Ronald. Apologies for being terse in the question! Can you perhaps just indicate what the `\x` does?  Also do you know if there's a tool/script you know of in PHP which can handle the grunt-work of decoding such packets now we know which format it's in?

Comment: The \x is just so i can use "binary" data. i.e. \x20 mean charactercode 0x20 (hex), which is a space (ascii 32). I will update the answer with some code

Comment: Awesome for that answer Ronald. Many thanks.  Appreciate it. +1

Comment: Any tips on getting the buffer with the `\x` already in?  I'm just getting it as a string of integers.

Comment: When you read the buffer, you don't have to add the \x, thats already "in place", just read into the buffer and fire the code (\xAB outputs a 'byte' with hex value AB, which is like the binary data)